# "ant clean" doesn't clean my project in a way I can use

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build-script

After I run `ant clean` , my project still needs to be "cleaned" in Eclipse, before I can run `ant release` successfully.

If I try to run `ant release` immediately after `ant clean` it will fail in the `-compile` component of the predefined build script

on the contrary, if I run the Eclipse version of cleaning all the projects, then I run `ant release` the `-compile` component will not fail.

Why is this? Why is `ant clean` a less adequate cleaning than the one Eclipse does? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution to your issue? I got the exact same problem.

Comment: @CharlesMorin No, I've been using gradle and android studio (intellij) since then. I would say ditch Eclipse at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would really like to do so but it's not an option unfortunately in my organization. Nevermind!

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic answer to this question. You will need to look at the implementation of the clean target in your ant script and figure out what it is doing wrong or not doing.

Comment: it is the one that comes with android tools

Comment: You will still need to look at the script to understand why it isn't doing what you expect.